# Constantly reassigning variables/Memory leaks/Printing strange characters?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Basically, I have a c project where I populate a 2d string array with contents of a text file. I iterate over the array and at each iteration I parse certain things from that string, assign those substrings to variables and then I concatenate it back into one string and send the new string off to another 2d string array. However, when I write the contents of the new array to another text file I get strange characters and other nonsense. Is me reusing/reassigning the same variables causing memory issues? Perhaps I need to include null terminators? I'm new to C so excuses my lack of knowledge. Here's an excerpt ..

```
    int result;
    
    if(strcmp(fcn, "sum") == 0)
    {
        result = (*comp[0]) (paramX, paramY);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fcn, "power") == 0)
    {
        result = (*comp[1]) (paramX, paramY);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fcn, "fibonacci") == 0)
    {
        result = (*comp[2]) (paramX, paramY);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fcn, "product") == 0)
    {
        result = (*comp[3]) (paramX, paramY);
    }
    
    char finalOut[40] = " "; 
    char finalOut2[] = " Result is: ";
    char finalRes[5] = " ";
    
    sprintf(finalRes, "%d", result);
    
    strcat(finalOut, ready[i]);
    strcat(finalOut, finalOut2);
    strcat(finalOut, finalRes);
    
    
    send(finalOut);
```

And all the code before it is kinda the exact same type of stuff. Constant re-assignment and reuse of the same variables at each iteration. Parsing substrings from the original substring and then using that data to make a new string to be sent to a new array. Keep in mind this is just a piece of what lies inside of a giant for loop. Other variables shown like "fcn" is what was declared before this excerpt by parsing a substring of the original string.

Excerpt of how im writing the contents of the new array to the new text file. This might actually be the issue.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    FILE *f = fopen(outFile, "wb+");
    fwrite(fifo, 100, sizeof(fifo), f);
    fclose(f);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```

To be frank, at the time of writing this code I was very unclear about what value should be passed in as the 2nd parameter of the fwrite method

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The problem is most likely elsewher than in the code you show. Did you check if the arrays are large enough?

Comment: And yes, all your strings should be null terminated.

Comment: Agree with @Jabberwocky.  If you're new to C, you'll soon learn that many kinds of bugs cause undefined behavior which can result in misbehavior in entirely unrelated parts of the code.  And the best way to find bugs is to actually run the program with a debugger (did you try that)?  So a mere "excerpt" is not enough for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: First bug I see: if `result` is more than 4 digits, the `sprintf` will overflow.  Second: `finalOut2` contains no space for any extra characters beyond the string that initialized it, so all of the `strcat`s overflow it.  In general, in C you cannot treat strings like first-class types.  They are fundamentally arrays of fixed size, and that means that all the onus of checking and managing their sizes falls onto you, the programmer.

Comment: Hey everyone, yeah sorry for my silly general questions. I reuploaded a smaller example that kinda encompasses the entirety if what I wanted to accomplish. Its essentially just breaking apart the string ..  using the data for a specific purpose. In the actual project its parsing substrings and using that data to call a function with the given parameter specified in the string itself.

Comment: Yeah, ^ that was a bad example my bad. It doesnt exactly reflect my project

Comment: No but I will try that now.

Comment: I figured maybe the issue was constantly reassigning the same variables at each iteration? Is that syntactically correct in c?

Comment: Its a school project so I was a bit hasty about posting more things specific to the exact code. I parsed the paramX and paramY by getting the substrings of each ready[i]

Comment: I recommend using `sprintf()` instead of all those `strcat()`: `sprintf(finalOut, "Result is %d ", result);`

Comment: The issue i believe is how im writing the contents of the new array to the new text file